# How can I determine what objects an object can "see" in 2d space?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am working on some software. I apologize for not putting this in any kind of real notation.

I have a series of points (x,y) and facings (θ). How do I find if a given point + facing is looking at another point? In this case B is looking at C and D, but not A. A is not looking at anything. C is looking at B and D. D is looking at A, B and C. A given point is looking at everything on the facing side of the tangent represented by degree θ.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $\vec{p}_i = (x_i, y_i)$ be the position of point $i$, and $\hat{n}_i = (X_i, Y_i)$ the unit vector it is facing at, with $\lVert\hat{n}_i\rVert = \sqrt{X_i^2 + Y_i^2} = 1$.

In a right-handed coordinate system, with $\theta=0$ in the direction of the positive $x$ axis, $\theta=90^\circ \text{ and } -270^\circ$ in the direction of positive $y$ axis, $\theta=\pm180^\circ$ in the direction of negative $x$ axis, and $\theta=270^\circ \text{ and } -90^\circ$ in the direction of negative $y$ axis, if point $i$ is facing in direction $\theta_i$, then
$$\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
X_i &= \cos\theta_i \\
Y_i &= \sin\theta_i \\
\end{aligned} \right. \quad \iff \quad \theta_i = \operatorname{atan2}\left( Y_i, X_i \right) \tag{1}\label{G1}$$
where $\operatorname{atan2}$ is the two-parameter form of arctangent, equivalent to $\arctan\left(\frac{Y_i}{X_i}\right)$ for positive $X_i$, but covers full $360^\circ$ by taking into account the signs of both $X_i$ and $Y_i$.  It is provided by most programming languages.

To determine the angle between the direction point $i$ is facing and the direction point $k$ is at relative to point $i$, we need to find the angle $\phi_{i,k}$ between vectors $\hat{n}_i$ and $(\vec{p}_k - \vec{p}_i)$.

We can use the fact that the angle $\phi$ between two vectors $\vec{a} = (a_x, a_y)$ and $\vec{b} = (b_x, b_y)$ is
$$\cos(\phi) = \frac{\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}}{\lVert\vec{a}\rVert \, \lVert\vec{b}\rVert} = \frac{a_x b_x + a_y b_y}{\sqrt{(a_x^2 + a_y^2) (b_x^2 + b_y^2)}}$$
In other words,
$$\cos\left(\phi_{i,k}\right) = \frac{\hat{n}_i \cdot (\vec{p}_k - \vec{p}_i)}{\left\lVert \vec{p}_k - \vec{p}_i \right\rVert} = \frac{ X_i ( x_k - x_i ) + Y_i ( x_k - x_i ) }{\sqrt{ (x_k - x_i)^2 + (y_k - y_i)^2 }}\tag{2a}\label{G2a}$$
or equivalently
$$\cos\left(\phi_{i,k}\right) = \frac{\cos(\theta_i) ( x_k - x_i ) + \sin(\theta_i) ( y_k - y_i ) }{\sqrt{ (x_k - x_i)^2 + (y_k - y_i)^2 }}\tag{2b}\label{G2b}$$
Because $\cos(\phi) = \cos(-\phi)$, you don't actually need to use inverse cosine (arccos) function at all, just compare the right side to the cosine of the half of the visible sector angle (since the visible sector is centered in the direction the point is facing, the limits are $\pm$ half the sector angle), to find whether point $k$ is visible to point $i$.

Comment: You can also save the trouble of computing the denominator on the right side of (2b): all that matters is whether the numerator is positive or negative.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that facing angles ($\theta$) are measured as in the trigonometric circle: $\theta = 0$ at point $(1,0)$ and $\theta$ increases counterclockwise. Then, for all upward facing directions we have $sin( \theta ) \ge 0$ and for all downward facing directions we have $sin( \theta ) \le 0$.

Now, for the given point and facing $\theta$ of the eye, construct a line passing through the point and perpendicular to the facing direction. The equation of this line will be $ax+by+c=0$ , where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are parameters of the line. Keep these parameters in memory.

Next, set up a loop: for each point in the set of points (except for where the current eye is), plug the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the point in the formula $ax+by+c$. If the sign of $ax+by+c$ is equal to the sign of $sin(\theta)$ then the point is visible to the eye; else the point is not visible to the eye.

There is a special case where the facing direction is horizontal and $sin(\theta)=0$ . The treatment of this case is left as an exercise to the interested reader.